# Redirect bash script output of application to file keeping the application interactive

Tags: bash, io-redirection

I'm running a bash script expecting occasional user input to continue processing the script. Is it possible to redirect the script output to a file while keeping the terminal output and keeping the application interactive, i.e. responding to my key presses?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tee` is designed for this purpose.  I wrote the script `sc`:

```
##!/bin/bash
while [[ $x != "X" ]] ; do
        printf "? "
        read x
        echo "User wrote: $x"
done
```

then ran it as follows:

```
$ ./sc | tee f
? The first line
User wrote: The first line
? another line
User wrote: another line
? X
User wrote: X
$ cat f
? User wrote: The first line
? User wrote: another line
? User wrote: X
```

Pretty rough and ready, but it shows how to `tee` off to a file.

Answer (score 1):

You can run the command under `script`, which will capture its entire output in the file `typescript` for you. See `man script` for other options

```
script
your_command...
```

Use Ctrl/D to exit the capture session